# How do I use tensor board with tf.layers?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

As the weights are not explicitly defined, how can I pass them to a summary writer?

For exemple:

```
conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
    tf.reshape(X,[FLAGS.batch,3,160,320]),
    filters = 16,
    kernel_size = (8,8),
    strides=(4, 4),
    padding='same',
    kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(),
    bias_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(),
    kernel_regularizer=None,
    name = 'conv1',
    activation = tf.nn.elu
    )
```

=>

```
summarize_tensor(
    ??????
)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends on what you are going to record in TensorBoard. If you want to put every variables into TensorBoard, call `tf.all_variables()` or `tf.trainable_variables()` will give you all the variables. Note that the tf.layers.conv2d is just a wrapper of creating a Conv2D instance and call apply method of it. You can unwrap it like this:

```
conv1_layer = tf.layers.Conv2D(
    filters = 16,
    kernel_size = (8,8),
    strides=(4, 4),
    padding='same',
    kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(),
    bias_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(),
    kernel_regularizer=None,
    name = 'conv1',
    activation = tf.nn.elu
)

conv1 = conv1_layer.apply(tf.reshape(X,[FLAGS.batch,3,160,320]))
```

Then you can use `conv1_layer.kernel` to access the kernel weights.

Comment: Conv2D object has no attribute `kernel`

Comment: The kernel attribute is not there anymore, there is `weights` now but I am not sure if `tf.summary.histogram("weights", conv1_layer.weights)` is enough.

Answer (score 9):

While Da Tong's answer is complete, it took me a while to realize how to use it. To save time for another beginner, you need to add the following to you code to add all trainable variables to the tensorboard summary:

```
for var in tf.trainable_variables():
    tf.summary.histogram(var.name, var)
merged_summary = tf.summary.merge_all()
```

Comment: could you please tell me where exactly did you add these codes?

Comment: It has been a while, but I believe you need to do it after you have defined the structure of your network and before you call `add_summary`.