# Module tensorflow.python.layers.layers has no attribute Conv2D

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a graph, where the convolutional layers are created with `tf.layers.conv2d`. It works, but I would like to see the kernel and bias in tensorboard. I've found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44731808/how-do-i-use-tensor-board-with-tf-layers), that instead of calling the `tf.layers.conv2d` function, I should create an instance of `tf.layers.Conv2D`. If I do this, I get this error:

```
module 'tensorflow.python.layers.layers' has no attribute 'Conv2D'
```

The code is the same as in the linked answer:

```
conv1_layer = tf.layers.Conv2D(
    filters = 16,
    kernel_size = (8,8),
    strides=(4, 4),
    padding='same',
    kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(),
    bias_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(),
    kernel_regularizer=None,
    name = 'conv1',
    activation = tf.nn.elu
)

conv1 = conv1_layer.apply(x)
```

Why is python not available to find `Conv2D`?

---

If I run `inspect.getmembers(tf.layers, inspect.isclass)`, I get an empty list as result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its because of the Tesorflow version that you have installed. Update to **Tensorflow** **version 1.4.0** and should work fine.

Comment: happens with 1.5 too