# Adding tensorboard to federated setting

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am new in using TensorBoard, and I want to add it to this project:

https://github.com/TalwalkarLab/leaf

My specific case is the FE-MNIST model, which is in here:
https://github.com/TalwalkarLab/leaf/blob/master/models/femnist/cnn.py

The challenge of adding tensorboard to Federated Setting for people who do not know the setting is that in here, have a server that aggregate the models, and we have random number of clients that does the training, and they have a Client_id.

I want to have a tensorboard folder for each of the clients, and log for the server model (which no training is done there)

I want to know how to access layers weights and biases, and store them based on the client ids, which is the place that is calling the training.

I have seen [How do I use tensor board with tf.layers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44731808/how-do-i-use-tensor-board-with-tf-layers)

in here it says that we can use

**Code**

```
for var in tf.trainable_variables():
    tf.summary.histogram(var.name, var)
merged_summary = tf.summary.merge_all()
```

(which I am not sure where should I add it)

How can I pass the client id to a session, so it can store in the respective folders?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the usage of tensorboard [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/get_started#using_tensorboard_with_other_methods).

In Tensorflow 2.x, Based on the documentation:

When training with Keras's Model.fit(), 
Adding the tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard callback ensures that logs are created and stored. Additionally, enable histogram computation every epoch with histogram_freq=1

```
model = create_model()
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

log_dir = "logs/fit/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)

model.fit(x=x_train, 
          y=y_train, 
          epochs=5, 
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test), 
          callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

Or another option is

```
def add_hist(train_vars, step):
    for i in train_vars:
        name = i.name.split(":")[0]
        value = i.value()
        tf.summary.histogram(name, value, step)

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
  for (x_train, y_train) in train_dataset:
    train_step(model, optimizer, x_train, y_train, epoch)
  with train_summary_writer.as_default():
    tf.summary.scalar('loss', train_loss.result(), step=epoch)
    tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', train_accuracy.result(), step=epoch)
    add_hist(model.trainable_variables, epoch)
```